# Insert another hierarchy into a sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I wrote the following in TSQL:

```
SELECT 
    x.PARENT, 
    x.ELEMENT,    
    MAX(CASE SPRAS WHEN 'D' THEN MAKTX  ELSE '' END ) DCol,     
    MAX(CASE SPRAS WHEN 'E' THEN MAKTX  ELSE '' END ) ECol,  
    MAX(CASE SPRAS WHEN 'F' THEN MAKTX  ELSE '' END ) FCol  
FROM 
  (
    SELECT  
        a.PARENT, 
        (CASE WHEN a.ELEMENT = a.PARENT THEN '' ELSE a.ELEMENT END) as ELEMENT, 
        b.MATNR, b.SPRAS, b.MAKTX       
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            'ALL' AS PARENT, 
            LEFT(PRODH, 1) AS ELEMENT 
        FROM sap_T179 
        WHERE PRODH != ''             
        UNION 
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            LEFT(PRODH, 1),
            LEFT(PRODH, 2) AS ELEMENT 
        FROM sap_T179 
        WHERE PRODH != ''          
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            LEFT(PRODH, 2), 
            LEFT(PRODH, 3) AS ELEMENT 
        FROM sap_T179 
        WHERE PRODH != ''             
        UNION 
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            LEFT(PRODH, 3),
            LEFT(PRODH, 4) AS ELEMENT 
        FROM sap_T179 
        WHERE PRODH != ''          
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            LEFT(PRODH, 4), 
            LEFT(PRODH, 5) AS ELEMENT 
        FROM sap_T179 
        WHERE PRODH != ''             
        UNION 
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            LEFT(PRODH, 5),
            LEFT(PRODH, 6) AS ELEMENT 
        FROM sap_T179 
        WHERE PRODH != ''          
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            LEFT(PRODH, 6), 
            LEFT(PRODH, 7) AS ELEMENT 
        FROM sap_T179 
        WHERE PRODH != ''             
        UNION 
        SELECT 
            'ALL', 
            'Without Element'
      ) AS a          
     LEFT JOIN 
    sap_MARAV AS b ON 
        b.PRDHA = a.ELEMENT
  ) AS x 
GROUP BY x.PARENT, x.ELEMENT 
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Now I'm trying to get another hierarchy under the section

```
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 
    LEFT(PRODH, 6), 
    LEFT(PRODH, 7) AS ELEMENT 
FROM sap_T179 
WHERE PRODH != ''
```

that is like

```
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT  
    LEFT(PRODH, 7), 
    MatNR AS ELEMENT 
FROM sap_T179 
WHERE PRODH != ''
```

I tried joins and a lot of other stuff but its not working at all.

Comment: Would you mind explaining "its not working at all"?  That looks to me like a valid SQL statement, but without a description of the problem, I can't even begin to help you.  Are you getting an error message?  Are you seeing unexpected data?  Is the column MatNR part of the sap_T179 table?

Comment: Also, please post your RDBMS (e.g., Oracle, SQL-Server-2008R2, MySQL, etc.)

Comment: Im using MSSQL SERVER 2012 and the Code on top works but I dont know how to add another UNION SELECT with a Column from another table, right now im just using the table "T179" for the last Hierarchi I need to add the "MARAV" table somehow.

Comment: So, you're saying that MatNR is not a column from sap_T179.  Not a problem - what's the relationship between the two tables?  Is there a common ID (or set of IDs) that they both share?

Comment: yes they both have PRODH
thats why I 
 LEFT JOIN 
    sap_MARAV AS b ON 
        b.PRDHA = a.ELEMENT but how do i Join with a Union?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you're looking to retrieve data from two different tables as another UNION statement.  You state that the relationship between the two is that both share the same PRODH column.

Given that, try the following (edit with the name of your table):

```
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT  
    LEFT(t1.PRODH, 7), 
    t2.MatNR AS ELEMENT 
FROM 
    sap_T179 t1
     INNER JOIN 
    OtherTable t2 ON -- rename this!
        t1.PRODH = t2.PRODH
WHERE T1.PRODH != ''
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now when I see it its totaly logical but I didn't get it by my self. :)

Comment: Happy to help!  If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.